# T-sql " where orderid %2 = 0" what does the %

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, where-clause

I was preparing Microsoft certification for SQL querying and I found this example:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('TK461-CustomersOrders' AS co)
SELECT [co:Customer].custid AS [co:custid],
[co:Customer].companyname AS [co:companyname],
[co:Order].orderid AS [co:orderid],
[co:Order].orderdate AS [co:orderdate]
FROM Sales.Customers AS [co:Customer]
INNER JOIN Sales.Orders AS [co:Order]
ON [co:Customer].custid = [co:Order].custid
WHERE [co:Customer].custid <= 2
AND [co:Order].orderid %2 = 0
ORDER BY [co:Customer].custid, [co:Order].orderid
FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, ROOT('CustomersOrders');
```

And then this explanation:
The T-SQL table and column aliases in the query are used to produce element names, prefixed with a namespace. A colon is used in XML to separate the namespace from the element name. **The WHERE clause of the query limits the output to two customers, with only every second order for each customer retrieved**. The output is a quite nice element-centric XML document.

Even when the description says it takes every second order for each customer it seems not to be doing that.
Even when custid <= 2 brings the first two customers I'm not sure what the %2 = 0 does since it do not bring (or at least to my understanding) every second order for each customer. For the first customer it brings 3 orders and for the second it brings two.
These are all the orders:

```
custid  companyname orderdate
1   Customer NRZBB  10643
1   Customer NRZBB  10692
1   Customer NRZBB  10702
1   Customer NRZBB  10835
1   Customer NRZBB  10952
1   Customer NRZBB  11011
2   Customer MLTDN  10308
2   Customer MLTDN  10625
2   Customer MLTDN  10759
2   Customer MLTDN  10926
```

and this is the result of the query (without the xml clause)
custid  companyname orderdate

```
1   Customer NRZBB  10692
1   Customer NRZBB  10702
1   Customer NRZBB  10952
2   Customer MLTDN  10308
2   Customer MLTDN  10926
```

Could someone explain me how the % works in this where clause?
I tried in many places but it always relate the % to the like operator, and I think this is not the case.

Comment: Had you started at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com) and entered `sql server %` in the search box, it would have offered `sql server % operator`. As for it returning every other second order for each customer, that assumes that the `OrderId` values are dense for each customer. Is that guaranteed in the problem statement?

Comment: It is hard to search on something like %.   Search on sql operators.

Comment: @HABO did you try that search?

Comment: @Paparazzi Yes, I tried the search. I started with Google and didn't get very far, hence the suggestion to start at MSDN since SQL Server is (currently) a Microsoft product. (And I just checked it again.)

Comment: @Paparazzi Although I was able to quickly navigate to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx) page documenting the modulo operator, the page did not specifically explain how to use it in a query to retrieve every other customer order in XML format. I was trying to provide the OP with a way to search for applicable information. As more products with clever names like `c?:` come out searching isn't getting any easier. Why not create `--c` just to annoy [Google](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433)? Should I apologize for the suggestion or its tone?

Comment: @Paparazzi When I enter `sql server %` in the search box at MSDN the _search box_ offers `sql server % disk time`, `sql server %`, `sql server % modulo` and `sql server % operator`. At that point I would choose `sql server % operator` since it appears that `%` is being used as an operator in the OP's query. The second search _result_ (of about 1,670,000) is an MSDN page (A primary, if often unhelpful, reference source.) for Operators (Transact-SQL). Of the ten classes of operators listed on that page, Arithmetic Operators happens to be the first. It isn't far from there to modulo.

Comment: @HABO Cool - something must be wrong with my config or browser.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%` is the modulo operator. The general form of `a % b` means "divide a by b and check the remainder". Here, you divide the `orderid` by 2, and check  for the orders without remainders (i.e., return only even `orderid`s).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I supposed it was related to the division, but I didn't consider the "remainder" in my tests.

Answer (score 1):

% is the 'modulo' operator in T-SQL. Here's how it works: take an orderId and divide it by '2' - if the result is 0, then select it.

So, your where clause is adding the condition of the select statement to return all results with orderId as an even number. Check your results, and you'll see that only even number orders were returned.

Comment: Thank you as well for the reply.  I was blinded and forgot about the "remainder" operator...  I never used it nor it was explained in the book.

Comment: Happy to help. Thanks for throwing 'answered' to our pal @Mureinik